# Retrieve element of object from list based on object key in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just wondering if there is a more elegant way to retrieve a value from a specific object in a list based on if the object contains a particular value or if I have to write something to traverse the list and look at each of the objects.  For example:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, url, value):
        self.url=url
        self.value=value

obj1 = C("http://1", 1)
obj2 = C("http://2", 2)
mylist = [obj1, obj2]

# I want to search  mylist and retrieve the "value" element if there is
# an object with a "url" value of "http://2"...basically retrieve the 
# value 2 if an element exists in the list with a url value of "http://2"
```

Of course if I knew it existed in the 1st element of the list I could retrieve it by:

```
mylist[1].value
```

However, in my case I don't know if that object exists in the list or not nor do I know in what position in the list it exists.

Comment: I dont get it. why not use a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse the list and look at each of the objects.

If you expect one match, you can use `next` with a generator expression:

```
res = next((i.value for i in mylist if i.url == 'http://2'), None)

print(res)
# 2
```

If you expect multiple matches, you can use a list comprehension:

```
res = [i.value for i in mylist if i.url == 'http://2']

print(res)
# [2]
```

Comment: That's what I thought.  I added a method to the "C" class to return the desired value.  Seems to be the best way to do it.